# Java program to search files

Tags: java, bash

I have a Bash Script which I tried to "translate" into Java. But if I execute them they don't have the same output.

I downloaded the BreachCompilation to exercise a bit in Java to search in files etc. But it simply doesn't output the same result. Is there something wrong with my Script?

(Please leave the Progress bar function apart)

Here are my scripts:

Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$#" != "1" ]; then
        echo "Usage: breach-parse <domain to search> <file to output> or \n breach-parse <domain to search><domain to search> <file to output>"
        exit 1
else
        master=results.txt
        path="$(pwd)/data/"

        touch $master
        total_Files=$(find $path -type f | wc -l)
        file_count=0

        function ProgressBar {
                let _progress=(${file_count}*100/${total_Files}*100)/100
                let _done=(${_progress}*4)/10
                let _left=40-${_done}

                _fill=$(printf "%${_done}s")
                _empty=$(printf "%${_left}s")

        printf "\r Progress : [${_fill// /\#}${_empty// /-}] ${_progress}%%"
        }

        find $path -type f -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file
        do
                grep -a -E "$1" "$file" >> $master
                ((++file_count))
                ProgressBar ${number} ${total_Files}
        done
fi
echo 
echo 
echo  Results:

cat $master
rm $master
exit 0
```

Java:

```
package com.company;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    List<File> list = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();

    public void listDir(File dir) {

        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        if (files != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
                    listDir(files[i]);
                }
                else {
                    list.add(files[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main lmao = new Main();
        File fi = new File("C:\\Users\\marpr\\Documents\\BreachCompilation\\data");
        lmao.listDir(fi);

        System.out.println(args[0]);

        for(File f : lmao.list) {
            try {
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f);
                while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    String line = scanner.nextLine();
                    if(line.contains(args[0])) {
                        lmao.results.add(line);
                    }
                }
            } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if(lmao.results.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("EMPTY!!!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("\nResults: ");
            for(String res : lmao.results) {
                System.out.println(res);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result for the input string: `"stefan.domanegg"` should be: `"stefan.domanegg@brennercom.net:654321"`

The Bash program returns the output as expected but the Java program returns `"EMPTY!!!"` which means there are no results!

Comment: just added the output

Comment: Please add `e.printStackTrace();` to the `catch` clause in your `public static void main(String[] args)` function, and run the Java program again. An exception might be being thrown and you don't know about it.

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: I added it but same result without any exception

Comment: You should print out each line your read in your while loop to see if you're reading what you expect from the files.

Comment: print lmao.list.length... it's probably 0. This is a ocmmon error I run into - some weird incompatible windows path formatting. Make sure you are entering your while loop in main, and print the lines of the file.

Comment: I just added this code: `for(File f : lmao.list) {System.out.println(f);}` and the result is as expected: ... C:\Users\marpr\Documents\BreachCompilation\data\s\h\6
C:\Users\marpr\Documents\BreachCompilation\data\s\h\7
C:\Users\marpr\Documents\BreachCompilation\data\s\h\8   ...

Comment: Could it be that the files are to big that it allways just loads half of the file and checks it?